# angularfire $save() method in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularfire

While I have no problem synchronizing data with the use of Angularfire's $save() method in angular directives such as ng-change, like for example:

```
<input ng-model="contact.name" ng-change="contact.$save()"/>
```

The problem appears when I try to do the same in my own custom directive. I have abridged my app to specify the problem:

This is the index.html with the dependencies:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <!--AngularJS-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!--ngSanitize-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.5.2/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <!--Firebase-->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <!--AngularFire-->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.4/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <!--Controller for the application-->
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <p editable="contact.name" field-type="text"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

We are just given a field with a contact's name.
Then the controller.js in question, for which I have created an id in firebase named "person1", containing just one key "name":

```
app = angular
.module('myApp', ['firebase', 'ngSanitize'])
.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject){
var contacts = new Firebase("https://contactsmgr.firebaseIO.com/contacts");
$scope.contact = $firebaseObject(contacts.child("person1"));
})
.directive('editable', function() {

    return {
       restrict: 'AE',
       templateUrl: 'editable.html',
       scope: {
            value: '=editable',
            field: '@fieldType'
       },
       controller: function($scope) {
           $scope.editor =  {
            showing: false,
            value: $scope.value 
           };
            $scope.toggleEditor = function() {
            $scope.editor.showing = !$scope.editor.showing;
            $scope.field = ($scope.field) ? $scope.field : 'text';
           };
            $scope.save = function() {
               $scope.value = $scope.editor.value;
               $scope.value.$save();
               $scope.toggleEditor();
            };
        },
    }
  });
```

The directive is invoked whenever "editable" is used in an element. It loads up the "editable.html" partial at first to replace it:

```
<!-- EDITOR.SHOWING SET TO FALSE BY DEFAULT -->
    <div ng-hide="editor.showing">  
    <span ng-bind-html="value"></span>
    <button ng-click="toggleEditor()">Edit</button>
    </div>

   <!-- EDITOR THAT APPEARS AFTER CLICKING "EDIT" BUTTON -->
    <div ng-show="editor.showing">
    <input type="{{field}}" ng-model="editor.value">
    </div> 

    <!-- EDITOR BUTTONS THAT APPEAR TOGETHER WITH EDITOR-->
    <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
    <button ng-click="toggleEditor()">Cancel</button>
```

The idea was for the value (which is bound to the editable directive's value) to be saved to Firebase with the use of $scope.value.$save() in "controller.js". Instead It throws this error:

```
TypeError: $scope.value.$save is not a function
```

Here is the same code pasted on plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/hdW731LjSuY0a1tscW6T?p=preview

Is it the isolated $scope of the directive that is at fault?

Comment: The plunkr doesn't throw that error for me now. That's one of the problems with just posting a link to a plunkr: you might've fixed the problem there, which makes this questions useless to anyone else. Please include the [minimal code to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question too. A plunkr is a great addition, but not a substitute.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen My sincerest apologies. The code I have provided on plunkr indeed does not throw an error because I have commented out the line 40 of controller.js that caused it. It is now uncommented in the fork: https://plnkr.co/edit/hdW731LjSuY0a1tscW6T?p=preview.  I will edit the question to include the minimal code aswell now. Thank you for your answer.